# The css file does not appear in inspect google

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Hi I'm an average in CSS but I did not understand why in many websites I find that this file does not appear and many theme I do not find the css file in charge of this class is this way in css I do not know.
I want to edit this class from the file but can not find the file?
Strangely, it's not the automatic properties of the browser.

[image]

Comment: It looks like this page is generated, including the class names. Also, I believe seeing just a <style> tag as the source means that the styles are actually on the page itself, not in a separate CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessary that class must have css written. Sometimes classes written to manage JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the final result of what is probably a `CSS-in-JS` approach that many popular tools out there provide. The original classes that the developer writes in their code are transformed into the sort of garbled looking classes when the build process is run.

The result is CSS classes that are unique and do not conflict in the traditional global CSS sense. This also means you cannot so easily track down the source of the code through your inspector unless the developer has generated and provided source maps as well.

A good example of one of these CSS-in-JS tools is Styled Components (https://www.styled-components.com/) but there are many others out there.